# How can I check if my website is not accessible via a certain ISP without being connected to that ISP?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, isp

Sometimes due to DNS issues on ISPs, my website isn't accessible in some of the ISPs. It's not possible for me to connected to every ISPs. But I know the range of IP addresses of each ISPs. How to do a IP spoofing and figure out if my website isn't accessible from certain ISP? The web server is on Linux.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What probelm are you *actually* attempting to solve? That some ISPs have bad DNS servers? Or that you have bad DNS servers? What you ask can't be done; IP spoofing is not a thing, and even if it was it wouldn't tell you how name resolution in a network was functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP spoofing is not the answer - you need to test from *within*
the ISP's network, or at least its DNS server.

For the ISPs you wish to check, you could try to find out the
IP address of their DNS server, then try to reach your website
while using their DNS server (ensuring that the IP is not
retrieved from a local DNS cache).

However, it's not a given that the DNS server of the ISP is
reachable from outside of its internal network.